# Different effects when clicking on a single element

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on an element with the class `.show_nav`, I want another element, with the id `#FW_Logo`, to get an opacity of `0.5`. When I click it again, it should get an opacity of `1`.

How can I do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
$('.show_nav').click(function() {
    $('.level1').toggle(500);
    if (clicked != 1) {
        $('#FW_Logo').css("opacity", "0.5");
        var clicked = 1;
    }
    else if (clicked == 1) {
        $('#FW_Logo').css("opacity", "1")
        var clicked = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for setting a variable, just use `toggleClass`.

Create a CSS class to set the opactiy.

```
.dim {
        opacity: 0.5
    }
```

And then toggle the class.

```
$('.show_nav').on("click", function() {
    $("div").toggleClass("dim");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that's even a cleaner solution!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way it is to create class with style `opacity: 1;` (if it is initial state use `opacity: 0.5;`) and just triger it on your element.

For example:

CSS

```
.clicked {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

JS (with jQuery)

```
$(".show_nav").on('click', function() {
    $('#FW_Logo').toggleClass("clicked");
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var clicked = 0;
$('.show_nav').click(function() {
    $('.level1').toggle(500);
    if (clicked == 0) {
        $('#FW_Logo').css("opacity", "0.5");
        clicked = 1;
    }
    else if (clicked == 1) {
        $('#FW_Logo').css("opacity", "1")
        clicked = 0;
    }
});
```